# Using sqlite database in SenchaTouch2

Tags: sqlite, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How to use sqlite database in senchatouch2..In model i used lik,

> proxy: {
>              type : "sql",
>              database : "ContactsDB"
>           }

getting error..plz provide sample code

Comment: Also How to connect with Mobile Payment Gateway

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what I have.  I just put that inside the config of the model.

```
config: {
    identifier: {
        type: 'uuid'
    },
    fields: [
        {name: 'username', type: 'string'}, 
        {name: 'password', type: 'string' },
    ],
    proxy: {
       type: "sql",
       database: "FullContact",
    }
},
```

remeber to include the reference:

requires:['Ext.data.identifier.Uuid','Ext.data.proxy.Sql',],

Comment: I am getting error like, http://localhost/e4bnew/data/proxy/Sql.js 404 (Object Not Found) ..How to solve this